# How to add PFX installed certificate to Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient, pfx

i have manually installed pfx extention certificate to my machine . How to get and pass in Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

i tried following way but no luck

```
    var myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    CertificateQuery certQuery = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateQuery();
    certQuery.FriendlyName = "TEST";    // This is the friendly name of the certificate that was just installed.
    IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certificates = await Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);
    var client = new HttpClient(certificates[0]);
```

Can someone help me on this how to add manually installed certificate in httpclient ?

Answer (score -1):

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "TEST", false); 
    //Change FindType to your liking, it doesn't support FriendlyName, 
    //maybe use your method?

WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

There you have it. Maybe use your certificate for the Add method but I don't know if they're compatible.

Comment: Not system.net.httpclient it's for UWP Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient